# Программно изменить цвет кнопки при нажатии

Tags: android

Нужно сделать так, чтобы пока палец касается кнопки, кнопка, скажем, синего цвета. А как человек отпускает - возвращает первоначальный цвет. В чём заключается проблема: стандартный метод закраски `buttonTT2.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(50,200,250,100))` работает конечно, но:

1)Он закрашивает не только кнопку, а ещё и вокруг кнопки

2)Я не могу понять, как вернуть первоначальный цвет кнопке после отпуска(цвет кнопки определить не могу)

Вот код лайаута, где лежат кнопки, которые при нажатии должны менять цвет...

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTT1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTT2" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="ZZZ"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/buttonTT3" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                //кнопка нажата, присваиваем один цвет

                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
               //кнопка отжата, присваиваем другой цвет


                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    button2.setOnTouchListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 2):

Согласен с  post_zeew. Другой вариант поместить shape в selector. Тогда можно решить какая форма у кнопки при этом будет менятьста только то что внутри shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid
            android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid
            android:color="@color/colorButtonPressed" />

        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/colorButtonPressedBorder" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid
            android:color="@color/colorButtonPressed" />

        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/colorButtonPressedBorder" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid
            android:color="@color/colorButtonDisabled" />

        <stroke
            android:width="3dp"
            android:color="@color/colorButtonDisabledBorder" />

    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

Comment: хорош... а куда это вставлять? или этим что-то заменять?

Comment: В <selector> как в примере post_zeew

Comment: ругается на строки c @color/colorButtonPressed - такой цвет найти не может, и подобные ему.